# How to add cumulative values in a JSON object in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add cumulative values in my JSON object. When I tried using `reduce` it's summing up all the values of particular key value. How can I achieve my desired output?

Sample JSON

```
[{
  "id": 28,
  "Title": "A",
  "Price": 10
}, {
  "id": 56,
  "Title": "AB",
  "Price": 10
}, {
  "id": 89,
  "Title": "ABC",
  "Price": 10
}]
```

required output

```
[{
  "id": 28,
  "Title": "A",
  "Total_Spent": 10 (Sum of A)
}, {
  "id": 56,
  "Title": "AB",
  "Total_Spent": 20 (sum of A+AB)
}, {
  "id": 89,
  "Title": "ABC",
  "Total_Spent": 30 (sum of A + AB + ABC)
},
.......]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a variable to hold the cumulative sum; map each original item to a new one, deconstructing the original and constructing the new item, with `Total_Spent` having the value of the cumulative sum, which gets updated with each item's price.

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 28,
  "Title": "A",
  "Price": 10
}, {
  "id": 56,
  "Title": "AB",
  "Price": 10
}, {
  "id": 89,
  "Title": "ABC",
  "Price": 10
}];

let cumsum = 0;
const newData = data.map(({id, Title, Price}) => ({id, Title, Total_Spent: cumsum += Price}));
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use array reduce for this task.

```js
console.log([
  { id: 28, Title: "A", Price: 10 },
  { id: 56, Title: "AB", Price: 10 },
  { id: 89, Title: "ABC", Price: 10 }
].reduce((acc, { Price, ...item }, index) => {
  acc.push({
    ...item,
    Total_Spent: Price + (acc[index - 1]?.Total_Spent ?? 0)
  });
  return acc;
}, []));
```